# Finding multiple solutions to the ODE $x'(t) = \frac{x(t)}{t^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a way to characterize infinitely many solutions to the ODE $x'(t)=\frac{x(t)}{t^2}$ with $x(0) = 0$. I don't necessarily want an answer, as much as I would like guidance in my approach. I found that $$x(t) = \begin{cases}0 & t=0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{t}} & t > 0 \end{cases}$$
solves this system. My idea to classify infinitely many cases is to find a family of functions $x_s$ that are $0$ until time $s$ and end up similar to $e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$ after time $s$. I thought about doing this by defining $$x_s(t) = \begin{cases}0 & t\leq s \\
e^{-\frac{1}{t-s}} & t > s \end{cases}$$
The problem is that we actually have $x_s'(t) = \frac{x_s(t)}{(t-s)^2}$ which doesn't *quite* solve the system, but is really close. I really think we need the $t-s$ term in the denominator, otherwise $x$ wouldn't be continuous but I don't know how to deal with the fact that this causes it to not solve the system. Can anyone help point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the infinite set of solutions
$$x(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t\leq 0 \\
  c\, e^{-1/t} & t>0 \end{cases}$$ with $c$ an arbitrary constant?

Comment: Of course! That is so much simpler than I was anticipating.

Answer (score 2):

Your "shifted" solutions are not right. Your equation is separable.
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{t^2}.
$$

After integration you get
$$
\ln|x|=-\frac 1{t}+c,
$$
or
$$
x=Ce^{-1/t},\qquad C>0.
$$
You also have the special solution $x(t)=0$.

The formula of general solutions works both for $t<0$ and $t>0$. Solutions for $t<0$ approach infinity as $t\to 0^-$ except for $x(t)=0$. The solutions for $t>0$ have limit zero as $t\to 0^+$. You can formally paste the zero solution for $t<0$ with either solution of the form $x=Ce^{-1/t}$ for $t>0$ by defining $x(0)=0$ but this pasted solution is not a solution of the given equation, since the latter does not make sense at $t=0$.

Summing up, instead of a shift, you have a dilation parameter $C>0$.

Comment: The first derivative (of the pasted solution) has a limit of $0$ at $t \to 0^+$ as well.